# Nuxt3: process & buffer are undefined

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3, nuxt-bridge

I'm building a Dapp using Nuxt3 but I have a few errors when using packages:

- [@coinbase/wallet-sdk](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-wallet-sdk)
- Axeptio

```
window.axeptioSettings = {
    clientId: '...',
    cookiesVersion: '...',
  }
  ;(function (d, s) {
    var t: any = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      e: any = d.createElement(s)
    e.async = true
    e.src = '//static.axept.io/sdk.js'
    t.parentNode.insertBefore(e, t)
  })(document, 'script')
```

I follwed [this](https://github.com/browserify/node-util/issues/43#issuecomment-1046110526) comment on github that allows Vite to get `process` working perfectly in `dev`but when building `yarn build` and `yarn start` I'm getting errors:

- `Buffer is not defined`
- The axeptio's script is generating an error so I have to comment it ...

How can I get rid of these errors ? May I use Webpack instead of Vite ? (and how to disable Vite)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Stay on Vite as a build tool. And also, please post the actual error that you're getting. Where is `Buffer` defined? Do you have a [repro] of this?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/thehedgeguy/nuxt3-bug-vite) is a minimal reproduction of the bug

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved it by adding

`yarn add buffer`

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer'

globalThis.Buffer = Buffer
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the specific file where you added the import lines ?

Comment: In nuxt I created a new buffer.ts in the plugins folders and added the lines from the answer. ->import ... and globalThis.Buffer =...  and append this line 
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp)=>{})

Answer (score 0):

3.10 has support for these polyfills.

```
import { Buffer } from 'node:buffer'
import process from 'node:process'
```

or you can provide your own

```
// ~/plugins/node.client.ts
import { Buffer } from 'node:buffer'
import process from 'node:process'

globalThis.Buffer = Buffer
globalThis.process = process

export default defineNuxtPlugin({})
```

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/releases/tag/v3.10.0